# Hide language settings on user account form (alternative to "dul")

Tags: 7

The user account form has settings for "Language" and "Regional settings" (to choose a timezone).

A common use case is that a site is only built for one language (e.g. German), but the admin user still wants to see it in English.

So the two settings need to be removed from the admin page.

There used to be a module for this, [DUL](https://drupal.org/project/dul). But it is now tagged as "obsolete" and "unsupported".

If someone finds a solution, this would be a place to share it :)
(this someone could be me.. we'll see)

And please no dirty js or css solutions.. I am sure there are better ways!

Comment: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/55299/disable-user-language-setting-in-user-edit-page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Administration » Configuration » Regional and language » Regional settings

```
/admin/config/regional/settings
```

[image]

Comment: Good to know! I somehow missed this one. It does not solve the language setting, but the other issue covers this.